# How to get checkbox from ListView android?

Tags: android

Iam getting Checkbox from OnItemClickListener by using below snippet

```
onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        Log.w("TAG","onItemClick clicked position :"+position);

        CheckBox cbx = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.c_checkbox);
        if(cbx.isChecked()){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                    "Checked position " + shoppingList.get(position).getItem(), 
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

I need to get all the positions to check which list item is checked.For that 
I used below snippet

```
int firstPosition = list.getFirstVisiblePosition();
             for(int i=firstPosition;i<=list.getCount();i++){
             View v=list.getChildAt(i);
             cbx = (CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.c_checkbox);
             if(cbx.isChecked()){
            }
         }
```

in below code cbx giving me null pointer exception.i used ViewHolder for the custom adapter.Please give me solution.why same thing is worked in OnItemClickListener?

Regards,
Rajendar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it think it could be

```
for(int i=firstPosition;i< **=** list.getCount();i++)
```

but that is just a wild guess.

why not use a checkable listview and then use [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#getCheckedItemPositions%28%29)?

Comment: I want the checkbox in left side

Comment: I did a mistake in ViewHolder and given "i<=" in condition that is wrong.Now it is working fine.